# How to install paramiko in python 3.7 version in windows

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

I installed pip using `python -m ensurepip --default-pip` and got version 18.1

Now I'm trying to install paramiko in the same using cmd `pip install paramiko` in windows.

But I'm getting error as `Could not find the version that satisfes the requirement paramiko. No matching distributional found for paramiko`
Please help me in solving this.

Comment: upgrade your pip and then try ,  this may help

Comment: https://bhch.github.io/posts/2017/04/fix-the-pip-error-couldnt-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement/